# Constantly getting this "Restarting Kernel" error message on JupyterLab (via Anaconda 3) on various .ipynb files

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

For the last couple of days, everytime I use Jupyterlab through Anaconda I keep getting this message to re-start my kernel after running the first 10 Jupyterlab cells (the 11th one onwards all fail every single time). The issue was with Tensorflow, I originally downloaded the newest version of Anaconda (which had Python 3.11 in it as the default python version). And I could not use Tensorflow at all since its not supported in 3.11 so I went back to the previous version of Anaconda (the one that has Python 3.10 on it - version 2023.03).

That's where the problems start, I did "conda uninstall ipykernel" or "conda remove ipykernel" <-- this is my base Python 3 (ipykernel) on the Anaconda prompt and removed it from the system then removed the jupyterlab then removed the whole thing by doing "conda remove jupyter_core" <-- which removed everything, including the Anaconda navigator and all the other stuff. I then re-installed everything by doing "conda install jupyter_core" (which didn't include the navigator for some reason) so I then did "conda install anaconda-navigator" then "conda install jupyterlab" (which wasn't there on the navigator or the core). And finally after removing the ipykernel on my first step, I then did "conda install ipykernel" but this still shows up:

## **Kernel Restarting**

## **The kernel for CIND850 labs/Implementation IPYNB Files/Model8_implementations_MNISTDigits_cpu.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically.**

How do I fix this issue? I'm very frustrated, one alternative I did was uninstall the whole anaconda program (both the navigator and prompt) from my control panel and totally remove it from my system. Then I re-install it from scatch (same version), then install the necessary packages through the prompt and I'm back to where I started with this Kernel dying message. Any idea on how to fix it?